# calculate area of four leaved rose with $ r=cos(4\theta)$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

[image]
This problem is from a past paper that I am doing, and I have managed to arrive to answer. However, it is different to what the examiners presented in their corrections.

My approach to this problem was to take the double integral in polar coordinates, such that r goes from 0 to cos(4x), and x goes from 0 to 2$\pi$. I then divide the area calculated by four, which should logically give me the area of only one leaf.

My result was $\pi$/8.

The examiner took instead the x limits from -$\pi$/8 to $\pi$/8 (how they came up with those limits, no clue), and then found an area of only $\pi$/16!

Anyone more wise than me can explain what is wrong?

Here my calculations:
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{cos(4x)} r dr dx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{cos(4x)} r dr = \frac{cos^2(4x)}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} cos^2(4x) dx = \frac{1}{16} \int_{0}^{8\pi} cos(2u)+1 du = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}
(I used substitution: 4x = u)
Therefore $A = \frac{1}{4} * \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{8} \neq \frac{\pi}{16}$

Comment: I would expect the area in a polar curve to be $\displaystyle \int_{\theta=\alpha}^{\theta=\beta} \frac12 r^2 \, d\theta$, which more or less what you have done   But I see eight petals rather than four.

Comment: I have put an image of the exam question... And it clearly shows only four petals.

Comment: I would have thought that the point corresponding to $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}$ (or $\theta=\frac{-3\pi}{4}$) and so $r=-1$ had the $x,y$ coordinates $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}2,\frac{\sqrt{2}}2)$ and is on a petal not shown on the image.  Similarly  $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$, and $\theta=\frac{7\pi}{4}$  (or $\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}$) are on other petals not shown.

Comment: @user3604362, i think the picture you have is not the right one. the graph of $r = \cos (4\theta)$ has eight of the closed loops, each about $\theta = j\pi/4, j = 0, 1, \cdots, 7.$ to get an idea, draw the $\pi/2$-periodic function $r = \cos(4 \theta) , r$ versus $\theta$ first.

Comment: Yeah, well.. I noticed that the exam indeed is misleading the students with that graph... I checked it myself, and the graph is not complete. Thank you very much though for the comments... It helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

one leaf of the clover is $-\pi/8 \le \theta \le \pi/8$ of which is symmetric about the $x$-axis, one half lies above and the below the positive $x$-axis. positive $x$-axis bisects this leaf. altogether, there are eight of them. area of this leaf is $$\frac 12 \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8} r^2 \, d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/8}\cos^2 (4 \theta\, d\theta ) = \pi/16.  $$

Comment: how do you get the $\theta$ values? like how do you know that that it is pi/8 ? It might be logical, but I would like to see it written out.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $\cos(4\theta)=0$, you get $4\theta=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\;$  and $\;\theta=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{8}$, where $n$ is any integer;

so one petal is traced out when $\theta$ goes from $-\frac{\pi}{8}$ to $\frac{\pi}{8}$.

Notice that the examiner could have also used $\displaystyle A=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{8}}\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(4\theta)d\theta$, and

that your method would have worked if you had divided by 8, since the rose has 8 petals (instead of 4).

[Notice that the graph is incorrect.]

Comment: Waah! That explains a lot! Thanks for both explanations! Helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome - the graph was highly misleading.

Comment: Yes, indeed. And that for an exam, that is really annoying. I guess one needs to be smarter than that then...